# What does GCC compiler do to type conversion? Why the output on mac and linux are different?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-conversion, undefined-behavior, shadowing

I did the type conversion of variable b(declaration outside the scope) in a scope and give a new val to b, and when the scope ends, the val of b seem to be wrong.

This happens on my macbook, which version of gcc is gcc-8 (Homebrew GCC 8.3.0) 8.3.0.   I tried the same code on my linux laptop whose gcc version is 5.4.0 and the code runs well.

```
std::vector<int> a = {1,2,3,4};
int b;
{
    size_t i = 0, b = a[i];
    //this time type of b is size_t

    ++i;
    b = a[i];
}
std::cout << "b = " << b << std::endl;
```

On my mac, the result is `b = 0`
On Ubuntu 16, the result is `b = 1`

What is the difference between two version of gcc on type conversion?

Or it is a bug?

Comment: `int b;` is never initialized - the result of `cout << "b = " << b << endl;` is *undefined behavior*

Comment: Did you use `-Wall` when compiling? Did it tell you anything interesting about your code? You can also try `-Wshadow`.

Comment: On top of the given answer `size_t i = 0, b = a[i];` looks fishy to me. I'm not sure if the standard dictates a initialization order here. `b = a[i]` might be executed first before `i` is initialized. Any language lawyers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not doing any type conversion, you're creating a *second* `b` within the scope, that, due to it having the same name, [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the outer `b`. This means that you're assigning something to the inner `b` and leaving the outer `b` untouched. Once the scope ends (at the closing curly brace), you're left with the (uninitialized) outer `b`, and printing it invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), which is exactly what you're experiencing.

This piece of code is semantically equivalent and might show a bit better what is actually happening:

```
vector<int> a = {1,2,3,4};
int outer_b;
{
    size_t i = 0, inner_b = a[i];
    //this time type of b is size_t

    ++i;
    inner_b = a[i];

}
cout << "b = " << outer_b << endl;
```